# Get the % of the filtered value and total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a new visual that will get the percentage of the filtered value vs total.

Format:

```
Name: (Slicer)

Value: Total value (Sum of column) | Selected Value | %Percentage
```

Example 1

```
Name: Name1

Value: 100,000,000 | 1,000,000 | 1%
```

Example 2

```
Name: Name2

Value: 100,000,000 | 2,000,000 | 2%
```

Any ideas on what's the best approach to achieve my goal.

UPDATE:

Here's what I created so far

```
Total P&L = 

var grand_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('_sp-Opportunity Fees and Variations'[Current P&L]),
    ALL('_sp-Opportunity Fees and Variations')
)

var selected_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('_sp-Opportunity Fees and Variations'[Current P&L]),
    ALLSELECTED('_sp-Opportunity Fees and Variations'[Current P&L])
)

RETURN selected_total/grand_total
```

I'm having an error:

> Parameter is not the correct type.

[image]

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a **Measure** like below-

```
percentage_grand = 

var grand_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[value]),
    ALL(your_table_name)
)

var selected_total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[value]),
    ALLSELECTED(your_table_name[value])
)

RETURN selected_total/grand_total
```

**Remember**, this is just idea/logic. Adjust yourself for your data and requirements.

=================

**Update:**

First create a **Custom Column** with this below code-

```
ABC = '_sp-Total Invoiced to Date - Current Month'[Total Invoiced Current] - [Current Cost & Expense]
```

**Now** you can use the Column **ABC** in the measure.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I'm still new at PowerBI. Here's what I have so far. I modified your code because the value its referencing is a Measure. I've updated my post to share what I currently have. Thank you!!

Comment: @NaofumiKun check my updated answer with new instruction below.

Comment: I'm still having errors. Parameter is not the correct type. Please check my update appreciate!!

Comment: You have created "Current P&L" as a measure or custom column?

Comment: Current P&L as a measure, I tried creating column with same formula as Current P&L `('_sp-Total Invoiced to Date - Current Month'[Total Invoiced Current] - [Current Cost & Expense])` but it's throwing me an error `(A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.)`.

Comment: Do your both column belongs to same table? or multiple table. It should be a very simple code like "column = your_table_name[col1] - your_table_name[col2]"